# Opinion on the icon of the logo please :)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, icon, illustration, critique

I am rebranding my personal work. I used to work with the name of Miss Graphics but was suggested that its too generic. I have now come up with a new concept. I would like to show Dolphin to represent Harmony in design and friendliness while incorporating the concept of graphics and design. I am presenting this brand as a solution oriented Boutique design studio.

So Dolphix is : Dolphin + Graphics + Fix

I would love to know what you think of the icon. Whether it is aesthetically pleasing and if it makes sense for the brand. Thank you.

[image]

Edit:

After reading your comments I decided to make edges of the font less sharp to match the Icon D so it goes better together. Also, I have adjusted position of the D so that hopefully it reads more like "Dolphix" and not "Olphix" as some of you pointed out. I have made two variants and I am hoping I can use both as variations depending on where I am placing it. I would love to know if the placement of the icon in the first one below reads as "D" and hence "Dolphix" now. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Note that if you want a full-scale critique, rather than a Q&A focussing on a single aspect, you may want to come to [The Looking Glass](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass), our chatroom dedicated to critique.

Comment: You may want to review the [**critique guidelines**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions). Asking for "general **opinions** about whether or not something is "aesthetically pleasing" is not a good question. There's no way to determine a **correct** answer - only answers which *may* meet *your own opinion*. - For what it's worth. I never saw a "D", until I read what it was *supposed* to be.

Comment: Wrzlprmft thank you. I will definitely check it out :) @Scott I knew about this so guideline that's why i limited the question to the icon only.. I apologize if I implemented it wrongly :) and thank you for your feedback about the D. That really helps

Comment: Your new version with written D and top icon is readable. The icon could be bigger, for ex. this big https://www.dropbox.com/s/a54nbaknbrk0dgy/NewDolph.jpg?dl=0 You can also draw more freely because it has no need to be D. Colors remove the steriliness. I guess you can well be in color.

Comment: I think you did a great jobon your icon and logo. Kept it simple and its easy to understand. Good job.

Comment: Thank you @user287001 ! This looks great. You have been very helpful 

Thank you Rani! Means a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's olphix + a shape in front of it. Let your name be visible as a whole. It's very difficult to mix an icon and a letter as one symbol without generating reading errors. You haven't succeeded.

It's much easier to write Dolphix and insert a separate icon.

Another thing: It somehow resembles a text in a medicine or food supplement package, like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9tp8msgejy9eyg/Olphix%20Cream.psd?dl=0. I believe something less sterile is welcome. An example with separate icon:

[image]

**Not asked:** name Dolphix (and Olphix) is already used, as you can easily find. You are in a danger to collect troubles, if you use it without careful research is it free where you live. If it isn't, do not use it without a written and signed clearance by the owner.

Circle near getting closed: Ten days ago you started with an unique shape. Unfortunately it wasn't easily readable as you wanted then. I saw it as a dog shape and suggested you to have a name which fits. It was this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqoxxzgsf1spgz7/BasseGr.jpg?dl=0 Site cleankeeping pushed the discussion into chat, because it had too much writing. But now you are near the same idea: a friendly animal. Rethink, if you can use your original shape. Or draw something even less formal and sterile with dolphins. One example: [image]

Comment: I see what you are saying..  I will try out a different placement :)
I looked up Dolphix.. there are none in the designing industry and certainly no business is using it in my country. I even looked it up on the domain site. So hopefully it shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: Oh just noticed the medical bit.. so experimenting with fonts should do? Will try it out. Thanx

Comment: I have to say I disagree with almost everything in this answer. I saw the image before reading any of the text in the question, and _Olphix_ never once registered at all for me until you said it. I immediately saw _Dolphix_ and automatically identified the shapes in the D as being water- and dolphin-based. To my eyes, I think the integration of name and symbol is quite successful here (which is not to say that separating the text and the illustration might not work better). I’d also never associate it with medicine or chemicals – far too whimsical for that.

Comment: I admit it sounds idiotic to say "this is like a printing on a medicine box" after I should already know it presents a design studio. We are all different and prisoned by our thinking habits. I have an unfortunate habit to lift up associations which should be known to be out of the circle of interest.

Comment: I appreciate both your comments. It's actually better to know how two different people view the same design. I will try out a few different versions today. And the original miss graphics was meant to be a signature and never a dog :p now I realized how messes up my starting point was. Thank you! So I have decided to go towards a solid icon sort of thing and not the signature or doodle as I originally intended :)

Answer (score 3):

Your name says *dolphin,* but your logo, and particular your icon doesn’t say *dolphin.* I know there is a tiny fin and waves, but this is more whispering *dolphin* than saying it.
Here are two quick sketches of how you could scream *dolphin* (if that’s what you want):

[image: Dolphin D sketch 1]
[image: Dolphin D sketch 2]

Another advantage is that it reads more like a *D* and thus makes your entire name more readable.

This connects to another problem (which is not exactly what you asked), namely that the typeface you use for *olphix* is not really matching your *D.* One simple thing that you could do (when keeping the logo as it is) is to fill the counters of the *O* and *P:*

[image]

Another problem with the *olphix* typeface is that it does not match the organic, wavy topic of the logo: It has sharp corners (as far as I can see) and emphasises on perfect circles and straight lines.

If you use your icon as a letter, I suggest to first finish the icon and then let it inform the typeface for the *olphix.*

Comment: I intended to keep it subtle so that's not a problem. I really appreciate the ideas though. Thank you! Apart from that, I really like your idea of filling up the O and P. I will definitely try that out when I do the fittings today. Also thank you for suggesting the sharp corners issue. I will try something that resembles the icon :)